# Cannot use (type []byte) as type io.Reader

Tags: go, io, byte, reader

I don't understand the error, this is my main.go that I execute in the machine "A":

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "github.com/mistifyio/go-zfs"
)

func main() {
    // Listen for incoming connections.
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "192.168.99.5:9977")
    if err != nil ...
    // Close the listener when the application closes.
    defer l.Close()
    fmt.Println("Listening on " + CONN_HOST + ":" + CONN_PORT)
    for {
        // Listen for an incoming connection.
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil ...

        //Handle connections in a new goroutine.
        go handleRequest(conn)
    }
}

// Handles incoming requests.
func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    // Make a buffer to hold incoming data.
    buff := make([]byte, 1024)
    // Read the incoming connection into the buffer.
    _, err := conn.Read(buff)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error reading: %s.\n", err.Error())
    }
    // ReceiveSnapshot
    ds, err := zfs.ReceiveSnapshot(buff, "tank/replication")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error receiving: %s.\n", err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s... done!\n", ds)
    // Send a response back to person contacting us.
    conn.Write([]byte("Received!"))
    // Close the connection when you're done with it.
    conn.Close()
}
```

Now, I show you the function ReceiveSnapshot from github.com/mistifyio/go-zfs/zfs.go:

```
type command struct {
    Command string
    Stdin   io.Reader
    Stdout  io.Writer
}

func ReceiveSnapshot(input io.Reader, name string) (*Dataset, error) {
    c := command{Command: "zfs", Stdin: input}
    _, err := c.Run("receive", name)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return GetDataset(name)
}
```

I have seen in golang pkg the doc of io.Reader:

```
type Reader interface {
        Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

Why do I receive the error...

- cannot use buff (type []byte) as type io.Reader in argument to zfs.ReceiveSnapshot:
  []byte does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)

...when I make `go install` ?

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? A []byte does not implement the Read method of an io.Reader, therefore it cannot be used as an io.Reader. Please work through the Methods and Interfaces chapter of the Tour of Go (starting here: https://tour.golang.org/methods/1)

Comment: I know that the message is clear but if I ask this it's because I don't understand (and I have read the tour...) the difference between `buff := make([]byte)` and the Read method `Read (p []byte)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you are missing a step in your logic when you think that `[]byte` would be equivalent to `Reader` just because the Reader's `Read` method receives a `[]byte` as a parameter.

Let me try to clarify:

Your `ReceiveSnapshot` function expects a `Reader` as a parameter:

```
ReceiveSnapshot( input io.Reader ...
```

In order for a type to fulfil the `Reader` interface, that type should itself implement this function:

```
Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
```

Note that the type should *implement* that function in order to be a `Reader`.

`[]byte` *does not implement* a `Read` function. It is just a coincidence that the argument to `Read` happens to be a `[]byte`.

In order for this to work, you need to send `ReceiveSnapshot` a proper `Reader`.

Luckily for you, having a `[]byte` and wanting to Read for it is a common situation so the API provides an easy way to do this:

https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewReader

You just need to send `bytes.NewReader(buff)` to your `ReceiveSnapshot` function instead of just `buff`.

Comment: Thank you so much! @eugenioy

Comment: I keep coming back to this super helpful answer, thanks so much @eugenjoy.

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer**: Wrap your buffer in a [Reader](https://tour.golang.org/methods/21) type by using [`bytes.NewReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewReader)

Alternatively, you could use [`bytes.NewBuffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer) with similar effect.

If the source is a string, you can use [`strings.NewReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReader).

The list of Readers goes on and on: https://golang.org/search?q=Read#Global

---

### Explanation of the deeper question

*The deeper question being: Why doesn't an array support the `io.Reader` interface directly?*

`io.Reader` supports the concept of reading from a general data stream for which **the total size is not necessarily known in advance**.  In order to support this, `Read` is called repeatedly until all input data is exhausted.  In many languages, similar read functions must be called at least twice, where the final call returns a flag indicating *end-of-file*.

By returning two values (one of which is type [`error`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error)), Go makes it possible for reading of arrays to complete in one-shot, *but only if the destination buffer is large enough to consume all available data* -- which isn't always known in advance.

The [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) interface specifies the signature and behavior of the `Read()` function:

```
func (T) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error)
```

> Read populates the given byte slice with data and returns the number of bytes populated and an error value. It returns an io.EOF error when the stream ends.

So due to the way the `io.Reader` interface works, a simple byte buffer is not capable of implementing it.  A wrapper structure is required in order to remember the state between subsequent calls to `Read()`.

For the sake of interest, here's an example showing how that can be implemented...

```
type MyReader struct {
    src []byte
    pos int
}

func (r *MyReader) Read(dst []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n = copy(dst, r.src[r.pos:])
    r.pos += n
    if r.pos == len(r.src) {
        return n, io.EOF
    }
    return
}

func NewMyReader(b []byte) *MyReader { return &MyReader{b, 0} }
```

*Notice, also, that the `[]byte` parameter to `Read()` is the destination buffer, not the source.*